# java Server was unable to process request Value cannot be null

Tags: java, web-services, apache, tomcat

I got this exception :

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null.Parameter name: input

How can I find the parameter `:input`? And, how do I fix the root problem? I am making a call from a Java client to a web method in ASP.net.

This is the code:

```
public org.tempuri.UpdateInsuredDetails_Output recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails(
        org.tempuri.UpdateInsuredDetails_Input l_input)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    if (super.cachedEndpoint() == null) {
        throw new org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException();
    }
    org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
    _call.setOperation(_operations[2]);
    _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
    _call.setSOAPActionURI("http://tempuri.org/RecieveMDMDataInsuredDetails");
    _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
    _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
            "http://tempuri.org/", "RecieveMDMDataInsuredDetails"));
    setRequestHeaders(_call);

    setAttachments(_call);
    try {
        logger.info("this is where i get the error:");
        java.lang.Object _resp = _call
                .invoke(new java.lang.Object[] { l_input });
        if (_resp instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException) {
            throw (java.rmi.RemoteException) _resp;
        } else {
            extractAttachments(_call);
            try {
                return (org.tempuri.UpdateInsuredDetails_Output) _resp;
            } catch (java.lang.Exception _exception) {
                return (org.tempuri.UpdateInsuredDetails_Output) org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils
                        .convert(
                                _resp,
                                org.tempuri.UpdateInsuredDetails_Output.class);
            }
        }
    } catch (org.apache.axis.AxisFault axisFaultException) {
        throw axisFaultException;
    }
}
```

this is how I call the method recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails:

```
InsuredDetailsLocator MDP_locator =new InsuredDetailsLocator(); 
            MDP_locator.setInsuredDetailsSoapEndpointAddress("http://mgnt184:8056/MDP_InsuredDetails_WS/InsuredDetails.asmx?wsdl");
            InsuredDetailsSoapStub service= (InsuredDetailsSoapStub)MDP_locator.getInsuredDetailsSoap(); 
            UpdateInsuredDetails_Input request_MDP =new UpdateInsuredDetails_Input();
            request_MDP.setSystemName(urlProps.getProperty("xxx"));
            request_MDP.setSystemPassword(urlProps.getProperty("xxxx"));

            request_MDP.setMS_ZIHUY(insuree.getMsZihuy());
            request_MDP.setKOD_CHEVRA(insuree.getKodChevra());
            request_MDP.setFAMILY_NAME(insuree.getFamilyName());
            request_MDP.setFIRST_NAME(insuree.getFirstName());
            request_MDP.setKOD_MIN(insuree.getKodMin());
//calling the method:   
UpdateInsuredDetails_Output response_MDP= service.recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails(request_MDP);
```

maybe the `input` that it ment is the one from the xml file :

```
<wsdl:portType name="InsuredDetailsSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="GetInsuredDetails">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetInsuredDetailsSoapIn" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetInsuredDetailsSoapOut" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="UpdateInsuredDetails">
<wsdl:input message="tns:UpdateInsuredDetailsSoapIn" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:UpdateInsuredDetailsSoapOut" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="RecieveMDMDataInsuredDetails">
<wsdl:input message="tns:RecieveMDMDataInsuredDetailsSoapIn" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:RecieveMDMDataInsuredDetailsSoapOut" />
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

Comment: The error seems to be quite comprehensible: put something into the `input` field of the request... Do you just call the `recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails` with a null argument?

Comment: the argument that i am sending to `recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails ` is not null- it's the argument `l_input`.    I want to put something into the `input` field but where can i find this argument?in the XML ?in the Java code?

Comment: Please post the code from where you call the recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails method. Seeing that would help a lot in trying to determine what he issue is.

Comment: I added to the origin question the main code , where I call the method `recieveMDMDataInsured Details`

Comment: Does `request_MDP` have a  `setInput()` method?

Comment: no , there are only SystemName, SystemPassword, MS_ZIHUY and so on

Comment: maybe the `input` that it ment is the one from the xml file - I attached some of it to the origin question

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be saying that `l_input` is `null` ... and it shouldn't be.

But `l_input` is a parameter to the `recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails` method.

So from this, I'd conclude that *that* method is being called with an invalid parameter.  Look at where the (your?) code is calling the method, etcetera.

---

If this doesn't help, add the full stacktrace for the exception to your Question, together with the code that calls the `recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails`.

(And please fix the spelling errors in your code.  It makes my brain hurt! "recieve" -> "receive" !!!)

Comment: i put this in the code :`if(l_input==null )logger.info("l_input is null");` and I didn't get this message -that's mean that `l_input` is not null.

Comment: I added to the origin question the main code , where I call the method `recieveMDMDataInsured Details`

Comment: maybe the `input` that it ment is the one from the xml file - I attached some of it to the origin question